# Java VM mismatch

Tags: java

I am trying to install Java Sunspot on Windows. I have Java already installed and doing `java -version` shows me I am running 64 bit version. In spite of this Sunspots keeps complaining that I am using a wrong Java Virtual Machine. I am using a 32 bit version running on a 64 bit version. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by:

1. Installing the 64 bit java JRE
2. Installing the 64 bit java JDK

Apparently, IMO the java SunSpot expects the architecture for the processor and java to be the same.

Once this was done I got Solarium running.